# How to access the n'th item of a float3

Tags: c++

Im not familiar with the C++ syntax but need to write a few basic lines of code.

```
float3 myValue = (1.0f,2.0f,3.0f);
float output = myValue[0];
print(output);
```

This code will return 3.0 and not 1.0 as i would have expected.
So my question is how do i get the n'th item of a float3?

Comment: `float3` is not a standard C++ type.  What defines it?  Is there any documentation?  Can you read the header files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to construct an object from  type `float3`. Without the details of that type, I can only speculate that the type has a constructor taking three floats, so the required syntax is

```
float3 myValue(1.0f,2.0f,3.0f);
```

Otherwise, if you are after a size 3 array of `float`, you can define it like this:

```
float myValue[3] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
```

Note that the C++ standard library gives you a handy array container, [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which is copyable, assignable, and altogether easier to use:

```
std::array<float, 3> myValue{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
```

Comment: ohh... how come its 30?

Comment: @user2339945 That was a typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you want an array of 3 floats but you are trying to create this with three `float3`.

Either you create an `float3` using it's constructor (if it is defined):

```
float3 myValue( 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);   // assigns 3 floats to float3
```

or you create an array of 3 `float`s:

```
float myValue[3] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
```

Now you can use

```
float output = myValue[0];  // to get first element of the container of 3 floats
```

---

The definition

```
 float myValue = (1.0f,2.0f,3.0f);
```

assigns only the last expression to variable because in **C++** (and C) [the comma is a binary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

Note that you might consider using efficient, specialized standard containers that will ease handling memory

`std::vector` or `std::array`